# How do I serialize an object to file using NSKeyedArchiver in NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 format?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nskeyedarchiver

Hopefully that title is clear enough. Anyways, it seems:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:rootObject toFile:path];
```

is restricted to `NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0`.

I need the format to be human readable [so xml]. If you're interested, this is part of project I'll eventually put up on github with a blog post about "How to Unit Test GPS Applications"

:-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `NSPropertyListSerialization` to convert it. Basically, assuming the object that you're serializing is called `myObject` and the ultimate file is stored in `myPath`, you would serialize it to XML using something like the following code fragment:

```
NSString *error = nil;
NSData *mySerializedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myObject];
NSData *xmlData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:mySerializedObject
                        format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                        errorDescription:&error]:
if( xmlData ) {
    [xmlData writeToFile:myPath atomically:YES];
} else {
    NSLog(error);
    [error release];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jason! I'm testing this now.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using the class method, try creating an instance of NSKeyedArchiver and using `setOutputFormat:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0` to specify XML format. The only downside is it'll take a few extra lines of code since to actually handle the serialization, it won't just return an NSData object in one step.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to encode the object class by using method 
-(void) encodeWithCoder(NSCoder *)encoder {

```
[coder encodeObject:name forKey:@"name"];
[coder encodeObject:address forKey:@"address"];
[coder encodeObject:position forKey:@"position"];
```

}